# How to apply sprite textures to matter.js bodies

Tags: javascript, textures, sprite, matter.js

I can't work out why my sprites are not working in matter.js. I am creating a car/football game and have disabled wireframes on the renderer but the sprites are still not applying correctly.
My first issue is that when I apply a sprite texture to a composite body (the car), the sprite does not render at all.
My second issue is that when I apply a sprite texture to the body of the car, the sprite does not rotate with the body (the sprite does not rotate at all).
My third issue is that when I apply a sprite texture to the ball (not a composite body), both the sprite and the body representing the ball become invisible. They ball is still visible to the engine but neither the body or the sprite can be seen on the canvas.

```js
function game ()
{
  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;


  // module aliases
  var Engine = Matter.Engine,
      Render = Matter.Render,
      World = Matter.World,
      Bodies = Matter.Bodies,
      Body = Matter.Body,
      Composite = Matter.Composite,
      Composites = Matter.Composites,
      Vertices = Matter.Vertices;

  // create an engine
  var engine = Engine.create();
  engine.world.gravity.y = 0.6;

  // create a renderer
  var render = Render.create
  ({
    //element: canvas,
    element: document.body,
    canvas: canvas,
    engine: engine,
    options:
    {
      width: window.innerWidth - 30,
      height: window.innerHeight - 30,
      wireframes: false
    }
  });

  var offset = 1;
  var wallSize = 20;

  var ground = Bodies.rectangle(400, 510, 1810, 60,
    {
      isStatic: true,
      friction: 0,
      restitution: 0
    });

  var ball = Bodies.circle(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight/2, 40,
    {
      mass: 5,// Used to be 0.5
      restitution: 0.95,
      friction: 0,
      frictionAir: 0.01,
    });
    ball.render.sprite.texture = "soccarball.png";

const carBody = Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(100, 100, [{x:200, y:200},{x:260, y:210},{x:260, y:220},{x: 200, y: 220}]);
carBody.render.sprite.texture = "car_sprites.jpg";
carBody.render.sprite.xScale = 0.06;
carBody.render.sprite.yScale = 0.06;

const frontWheel = Matter.Bodies.circle(100 -20, 115, 8);
const rearWheel = Matter.Bodies.circle(100 +20, 115, 8);

const car = Body.create
({
  parts: [carBody, frontWheel, rearWheel],
  inertia: 100000,
  friction: 0,
  mass: 100,
  restitution: -1,
});



  var floor = Bodies.rectangle(window.innerWidth/2, window.innerHeight + offset, window.innerWidth + 2 * offset, wallSize,
    {
      isStatic: true, friction: 0
    });


  World.add(engine.world, [ground, car, ball, floor]);



  // MAIN lOOP
    function cycle()
  {
    requestAnimationFrame(cycle);
  }
  cycle();







  // run the engine
  Engine.run(engine);
  //Engine.update(engine);

  // run the renderer
  Render.run(render);


  }



window.onload = game();









///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/*
function checkButtons()
{
 if(keys["68"]) // KEY_D
 {
   if(car.speed < 10)
   {
     //Body.applyForce( car, {x: car.position.x, y: car.position.y}, {x: 0.5, y: 0})
     let force = (0.001 * car.mass);
     Body.applyForce(car,car.position,{x:force,y:0});
     //console.log("Car Speed: " + car.speed);
   }
 }

 if(keys["87"]) // KEY_W
 {
   if(onGround())
   {
     carAvailableJumps--;
     let verticalForce = (-0.013 * car.mass);
     Body.applyForce(car,car.position,{x:0,y:verticalForce});
   }
   if(carAvailableJumps > 0)
   {
     if(!onGround() && keys["68"]) // KEY_D
     {
       carAvailableJumps--;
       let rotationalForce = (0.0009 * car.mass);
       Body.applyForce(car,{x: (car.position.x - carWidth/2), y: (car.position.y)},{x:0,y:-rotationalForce});
     }
     if(!onGround() && keys["65"]) // KEY_A
     {
       carAvailableJumps--;
       let rotationalForce = (0.0009 * car.mass);
       Body.applyForce(car,{x: (car.position.x - carWidth/2), y: (car.position.y)},{x:0,y:rotationalForce});
     }
   }
 }


 if(keys["83"]) // KEY_S
 {

 }

 if(keys["65"]) // KEY_A
 {
   if(car.speed < 10)
   {
     //Body.applyForce( car, {x: car.position.x, y: car.position.y}, {x: 0.5, y: 0})
     let force = (-0.001 * car.mass);
     Body.applyForce(car,car.position,{x:force,y:0});
     //console.log("Car Speed: " + car.speed);
   }
 }
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
<head>
  <title>This is the title</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="div">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"</canvas>
    <script src="matter.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="internethelp.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You are supposed to draw the car and other sprites yourself on the canvas. Matter only calculates the coordinates in the physics world for you. You have to apply those coordinates to the objects that you draw in your canvas.

Comment: Much appreciated, I finally managed to get something working. Although I'm still not sure why matter.js offers sprite texture functionality if it cannot be comprehensively utilised.
Regardless, thanks for your help

Comment: I have absolutely no idea how to close this question now it has been answered

Comment: I can copy my comment to an answer and then you can mark it as the correct answer :) BTW: the sprite functionality in matter is meant as a quick and dirty preview, but not for actual game rendering.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are supposed to draw the car and other sprites yourself on the canvas. Matter only calculates the coordinates in the physics world for you. You have to apply those coordinates to the objects that you draw in your canvas.

This is an example where the matter coordinates are read, and then used to position a DIV element in the DOM

```js
let physicsBox = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, w, h);
Matter.World.add(world, [physicsBox]);

let div = document.createElement("box");
document.body.appendChild(div);

// draw
let pos = physicsBox.position;
let angle = physicsBox.angle;
let degrees = angle * (180 / Math.PI);

div.style.transform = "translate(" + (pos.x - 10) + "px, " + (pos.y - 10) + "px) rotate(" + degrees + "deg)";
```